# 5m long 2 x 4 on Swing Set

Tags: load-bearing

We have had a swing set built in between two platforms on a climbing frame.

There are two 5m long runs of 2 x 4 with a foot in between them.  In that foot width there are monkey bars.  We have 4 swings and have had to attach wood between to reduce movement BUT we have drilled holes for 8 swing hooks and all the monkey bars were drilled too.  They are held with long screws into the juxtaposing legs / platforms.  I have three kids and it moves a LOT when they swing.  I’m VERY anxious that it isn’t safe or that the load bearing capacity is insufficient.  It is not supported in the middle.  Can anyone help?  Am I being paranoid?

Comment: A picture would help, but I'd be nervous too. 2x4s are practically spaghetti, and 16' is far too long a span *for their own weight alone* let alone any static load. Nevermind dynamic load.  That seems so improbable that I wonder if you're using the term "2x4" correctly...

Comment: I would be concerned with an 8’ span with today’s lumber and I work in a lumber mill, I hear a big Snap coming soon.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information before we have a chance to help you, but I agree with the others; this ain't safe.

Comment: I would be concerned!!  most swing sets that I have seen use a 4 x 6 Min as the top cross bar, I cannot even imagine a 2x4 spanning 5m. Like the rest of the comments 2x4 lumber is not recommended. DO you have a picture you could post.